# Is it possible to query a field for one of two values in a SOLR bf query?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to write a query that boosts on whether a "product" field contains one of two values where previously I only cared about one such value.

My previous query was essentially the following:

```
query({!v=products:PRODUCT1})^2.000
```

What I attempted to do is:

```
query({!v=products:(PRODUCT1 PRODUCT2)})^2.000
```

The default operator is OR, so I thought this would do what I expected, but instead I received an error message about an "undefined field 'PRODUCT2'".

Since then I've attempted many combinations of using ifs, exists, ors, and querys to try to come up with a solution allowing me to find whether 'products' contains one of the two values, and the best I could come up with was to add two separate queries with separate boosts to the bf query, but that's not preferred because I only want the entity to receive the boost for one of the products, not both.

I've searched high and low for good documentation on how to accomplish what I'm looking for and have so far been unable to find what I assume to be a very simple solution to a common problem. Any help on the matter would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the **bf** parameter you need to set *defType* as *eDismax* or *dismax*. There are several ways to accomplish what you're asking and one solution is the following:

```
if(termfreq(products,"PRODUCT1"),3,if(termfreq(products,"PRODUCT2"),2,1))
```

where the field products will be boosted by 3 in case it contains PRODUCT1, by 2 if it contains PRODUCTS2 and by 1 if it doesn't contain either. Obviously that's just an example and can be changed according your needs. Please find below the complete query.

```
https://<MY_SERVER_NAME>:9443/solr/<MY_COLLECTION>/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&bf=if(termfreq(products%2C%22PRODUCT1%22)%2C3%2Cif(termfreq(products%2C%22PRODUCT2%22)%2C2%2C0))
```